# Possible to rebuild table with CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Is it possible to rebuild a table looking like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>information 1</td>
        <td>information 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

to something like this with CSS?:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>information 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>information 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why I am asking is because this table, which is filled with content in a `div`, doesn't look nice when I minimize the `div` for a mobile display.

UPDATE, Reason why I need to do this:
We are building a website for a customer that want's responsive design. The "problem" is that the customer dosen't know html/css that good, so he/she uses a WYSIWYG-editor when providing the content to pages. And of course, he/she knows Microsoft Office, and build the content like it's done in that program, with tables.

Comment: is there supposed to be a difference between the first and second code blocks?

Comment: So, you want to move a cell to another row using CSS? In short.. no. Technically, you could make it appear as such but that would be some narly CSS.

Comment: @crowjonah the difference is that code block one row with two cells, code block two has two rows with one cell.

Comment: You are misusing tables. Important thing of an unbreakable table row is that you can easily compare (or select) several values. If it's not important in your case, you should use divs.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov According to who?  A table is a collection of tags that express the relationship between individual pieces of data.  The fact that they are displayed in a grid by default just means *that's how it's displayed by default*, nothing more.  Taking tabular data and shoving into tags that are void of semantic information is just as bad as shoving non-tabular data into a table (tables for layout).

Comment: @cimmanon I look at the `<table>` (and related tags) as on the HTML implementation of a "table" as the visual display method. Using it in this particular case would be just as wrong as using header tags to what actually a paragraph.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov The actual specs say nothing of the sort:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-table-element.html#the-table-element.  They describe how the User Agent is meant to render the table by default, define the correct tab order of the cells for keyboard users, and specify that they should not be used for layout.  "User agents are encouraged to render tables using these techniques whenever the page does not use CSS and the table is not classified as a layout table."

Comment: @cimmanon See [the concept of the table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/attributes-common-to-td-and-th-elements.html#concept-table). Our disqussion leads to nothing; I've explained the reason of my downvoting. And we both agree that table in this case is misused, don't we?

Comment: @PavloMykhalov I can't do anything if the customer that are populating the pages with tables. I am just trying to make things look nice on the mobile device. That's why I asked about rebuilding the table. So I don't understand your downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can effectively wrap `td`s by using media queries and applying css to float the cell into what looks like the next row. You'll want to provide some nice visual queues to help people figure out what they're seeing, though. [Here's a fiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/crowjonah/7Jvnw/) – resize the preview window.

Using your original markup, and applying the following CSS will wrap the second `td` when the window is less than 400px wide:

```
td {width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    td {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
    }
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with css (at least not easily), as that only affects the presentation of markup. You could certainly do it with javascript however if you detect that the user is coming to your site using a mobile browser. The question of how you do these things is far out of the scope of your original question however.

A lot of web sites have a mobile version and non mobile version. There are prewritten scripts out there to detect the user-agent in PHP, Javascript, etc etc.

Comment: We are building a website for a customer that want's responsive design. The "problem" is that the customer dosen't know html/css that good, so he/she uses a WYSIWYG-editor when providing the content to pages. And of course, he/she knows Microsoft Office, and build the content like it's done in that program, with tables. :)

Comment: @Raskolnikoov - then you are doing it wrong! If the format your customer is giving you the designs in doesn't contain clean `html`, rewrite it! Or best, ask them to mock it up using photoshop and then just create the thing yourself!

Answer (score 0):

I understand you problem, this would solve it. (ugly fix)

```
td {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Rather use divs and css, not tables at all ;)

Comment: If its tabular data, tables is appropriate.